# PHP PDO: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Tags: php, pdo

I've clearly done something quite silly here. Can anyone guide me?

Here's how I have things set up:

Database.php:

```
class Database extends PDO {

/**
 * Connect
 */
public function __construct($file = 'db_config.ini') {
    if (!$settings = parse_ini_file($file, TRUE)) throw new exception('Unable to open ' . $file . '.');

    $dns = $settings['database']['driver'] .
    ':host=' . $settings['database']['host'] .
    ((!empty($settings['database']['port'])) ? (';port=' . $settings['database']['port']) : '') .
    ';dbname=' . $settings['database']['schema'];

    parent::__construct($dns, $settings['database']['username'], $settings['database']['password']);
}

}
```

Team.php:

```
class Team {

private $_db;     

/**
 * getTeamMembers - Get team member UserIDs from TeamID
 * 
 * @param int $teamID
 * @return array UserIDs 
 */
public function getTeamMembers($teamID) {
    $result = "";
    $STH = $this->_db->query("SELECT FirstName FROM UserDetails WHERE TeamID = '$teamID'");
    $result = $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $result;        
}
}
```

Page code:

```
try {
    $db = new Database();
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
    $team = new Team($db);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error connecting to database: </p>".$e->getMessage();
}

$teamMembers = $team->getTeamMembers($teamID);
```

Error message:

`Call to a member function query() on a non-object in Team.php on line 20`

Line 20: `$STH = $this->_db->query("SELECT FirstName FROM UserDetails WHERE TeamID = '$teamID'");`

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can you show us your `__construct()` for Team?

Comment: @MickHansen There is no `__construct()` in Team.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that

```
private $_db;
```

is not set you should do something likje

```
class Team {

private $_db;     

function __construct($db){
   $this->_db = $ddb
}

public function getTeamMembers($teamID) {
    $result = "";
    $STH = $this->_db->query("SELECT FirstName FROM UserDetails WHERE TeamID = '$teamID'");
    $result = $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $result;        
}

}
```

Comment: Doh! I missed the __construct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're making a instance of Team with an $db but it never gets called in the team-class.